# Reverse Proxy redirecction http to https

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, https, reverse-proxy

I have a reverse proxy http to https. The page asks me for my username and password. However, when I enter my credentials it redirects me back to the home page. What I have to do to get inside?

This is my virtual host:

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80
```

```
    ServerName myserver
    CustomLog "logs/access_proxy_log" combined
    ProxyRequests off
    SSLproxyEngine On
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    ProxyPass /  https://direccionip/
    ProxyPassReverse /  https://direccionip/
```

Answer (score 0):

[this link](http://www.giuseppeurso.eu/en/redirect-from-http-to-https-and-viceversa-with-apache-proxypass/) will help you to 301 from **http to https** easily.